# Issue creating consolidated SQL script with multiple ALTER & UPDATES to one table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-scripts

I am working on a consolidated SQL script that needs to

1. Add a datetime column named AdjudicatedDateTime to the WarrantyAdjudicationStaging table.
2. Add a default date of GETDATE() for new entries into the table
3. Update old records with NULL values of the AdjudicatedDateTime

The statements seem to run fine alone, but I need them to run together.When I attempt to run them together I get the following error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 27
> Invalid column name 'AdjudicatedDateTime'

```sql
USE NATesterData
ALTER TABLE WarrantyAdjudicationStaging
ADD AdjudicatedDateTime datetime

USE NATesterData
ALTER TABLE WarrantyAdjudicationStaging
ADD CONSTRAINT DF_WarrantyAdjudicationStaging DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR AdjudicatedDateTime

USE NATesterData
UPDATE WarrantyAdjudicationStaging
SET AdjudicatedDateTime = AuditResults.AdjudicatedDateTime
FROM WarrantyAdjudicationStaging was
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MAX(dateTimeRun) AdjudicatedDateTime, was.WarrantyAdjudicationGroupID
    FROM WarrantyAdjudicationStaging was
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT WarrantyAdjudicationGroupID
        FROM WarrantyAdjudicationStaging
        WHERE WarrantyAuditKey IS NULL
    ) exceptions
    ON was.WarrantyAdjudicationGroupID = exceptions.WarrantyAdjudicationGroupID
    INNER JOIN WarrantyUsageAudit wua
    ON was.WarrantyAuditKey= wua.WarrantyAuditKey
    GROUP BY was.WarrantyAdjudicationGroupID
) AuditResults on was.WarrantyAdjudicationGroupID = AuditResults.WarrantyAdjudicationGroupID
WHERE WAS.AdjudicatedDateTime IS NULL
AND WarrantyAuditKey IS NULL
```

Comment: So, what's the problem? What is your question? Why 3 `USE` statements, when they are define the same database?

Comment: When I execute the query I get this "Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 27
Invalid column name 'AdjudicatedDateTime'."

Comment: Put a GO between each block. Remove the unnecessary USE statements. You can combine the first two bocks into one statement... add a column with a default constraint. The syntax is straight-forward.

Answer (score 1):

Add a     GO    after the statements to split them in batches

Comment: Note that depending on what is sending the statements `GO` could cause further errors. `GO` is not a Transact-SQL Keyword, it's an IDE keyword, used by applications such as SSMS and Azure Data Studio, and CLIs such as `sqlcmd` and `sqlcli`.